# Add elementor group Controls to class outside the main elementor class or main Render function

Tags: wordpress, elementor

At this time I have the code with Elementor group controls and render function. `register_controls` works well for classes used in render function. Example code: `'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .testsize` controls Typography of  `<h1 class="testsize>` because its in the render function, but I have .testsize classes outside the render function (Just HTML pasted in page) and controls are not working for them. Maybe That's how it should be, but I need to register controls for all .testsize classes, it does not matter classes are used in `render()` or not, controls must work for all. Can you help me? Thank you

```
protected function _register_controls() {

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'content_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );

        $this->add_group_control(
            \Elementor\Group_Control_Typography::get_type(),
            [
                'name' => 'title_typography',
                'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .testsize',
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }
    protected function render() {

        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        echo '<h1 class="testsize">TEST</h1>';

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy Fix. Just delete {{WRAPPER}}  from `'selector' => '{{WRAPPER}} .testsize',` and problem is solved. It's not usable while live editing but works after saving the progress.